# Orthogonality and QR factorization

Tags: orthogonality, least-squares

I need help with part B

[image]

I'm guessing since $A^TA = LL^T$, and $R^TR = LL^T$, then $R=L^T$ or $R=L$ but since it can't be defined which one, it is false? I'm I correct? who would I elaborate on this?

Comment: Please, **have a responsible behavior**: this question is entitled "orthogonality and QR factorization" and you had one or two hours ago, a previous question (to which you give no reference) entitled "QR factorization and orthogonality" (a very different title) one on part b) of an exercise, the other on part a) of the very same exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first reason for which one cannot conclude $R=L^T$ is that it is always possible to insert a diagonal matrix $D$ with diagonal entries $\pm1$ and its inverse $D^{-1}=D^T$ in such a way that:

$$R^TD^TDR=LL^T$$

This identity can be written :

$$(DR)^TDR=LL^T$$

with $DR$ being still an upper diagonal matrix ; thus, assuming that we could identify $R=L^T$, we could as well make identification $DR=L^T$ which is incompatible with $R=L^T$...